# JQuery code syntax issue? ("Inline control structures are not allowed")

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I have a bit of JQuery that creates a mobile menu for a responsive design. I ran the code through a code sniffer and it's telling me that "`Inline control structures are not allowed`".

The area of code in question is:

```
 else {
    $('#main-menu li').each(function () {
      if ($(this).children('ul').length)
        $(this).append('<span class="drop-down-toggle"><span class="drop-down-arrow"></span></span>');
    });
```

... and the specific line from the above is:

```
if ($(this).children('ul').length)
```

I tried to Google search "*Jquery inline control structures*" but did not come up with much.

Here is a pastebin of the [entire function](http://pastebin.com/yWtpTjFz) for reference. I am guessing the code can be rephrased but I have no reference on which to change it. The code actually works so I am not sure if it's necessarily a syntax error per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably wants you to use braces:

```
else {
    $('#main-menu li').each(function () {
      if ($(this).children('ul').length) {
        $(this).append('<span class="drop-down-toggle"><span class="drop-down-arrow"></span></span>');
      }
    });
```

It is always safer to use braces with `if` and `else`.  It never causes a problem and can occasionally prevent an accidental error (often when later editing the code).

Answer (score 0):

If I am ware, it is a simple syntax warning.
Try to use `{ }`.